PushManager subscription - AbortError: DOMException: Error retrieving push-subscription - Firefox for Android
On Firefox for Android / Fennec (newest version) I cannot subscribe to push-notifications.
You can check it out on cleverpush.com.
It's the same problem as mine.
My script subscribe.js should do the following:

Get permissions for sending Notifications - works fine

check for an existing subscription of this browser / device (ServiceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription();) - this works fine on Safari, Chrome and Firefox for Windows, Linux and macOS. It fails on Firefox for Android / Fennec (F-Droid).
The error is an AbortError: DOMException: Could not retrieve push subscription.. The same error happens on cleverpush.com with Firefox for Android / Fennec.

When the user clicks a Button "Register for Push-Notifications", it executes const subscription = await ServiceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe(...);. Same error like in (2.)


Many thanks if someone can tell me "this is a bug from mozilla" or "you made some mistake, here the explanation" or "this question has already answers here: ..."!

I just tested Firefox v128 on Android with this demo: https://pushpad.xyz/demo and I successfully receive the notifications. Does your device work properly on that page or you get the same error?

Then the problem might come with "Fennec F-Droid". pushpad.xyz doesn't work either. Every other browser worked.
